# Performance issue onDraw takes to long

Tags: java, android, performance, drawing, rendering

I'm drawing about 5000 lines on a View via canvas onDraw(). I'm panning and zooming within the view so the onDraw gets called alot to draw the 5000 lines.
I did measure the milliseconds with `SystemClock.uptimeMillis();` and the onDraw talkes 35 milliseconds for evey call which is just to slow.
While zooming I can actually see it jumping...

I already did set the hardwareAcceleration to true but that didn't change anything. I think the for loop might be to slow in getting the values.

Here is the code which takes to long:

```
    // Plot all lines on the view
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(line[i].getPktStart().getX(),
                line[i].getPktStart().getY(), line[i]
                        .getPktEnd().getX(), line[i]
                        .getPktEnd().getY(), lineColor);
    }
```

The value "count" is around 5000.
The line object is just a class which holds X and Y of start point and end point of the line.

Do you have any suggetions to get it running faster? Is it because the array is too big? I thought 5000 values shouldn't be a problem...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Path object? 
Also have you tried to use floats in your object to avoid type conversion while drawing it?

I'm not experienced with drawing CAD on android, but when i was using such programs on desktop or android i noticed that while you are dragging something, the image stays still. So you need to investigate code that save you drawing to a cache(bitmap) for that moment and not use draw line 5K times for every onDraw call. Also i think you already know that when you zoom in/out some layers shouldn't be visible if they are not representing meaningful information for that layer. Did you look for AutoCAD for android? How do they do it? I think you should search for drawing optimisations...

Comment: I need to plot actual lines or is Path ans faster? I might try to get rid oft the casting

Comment: Okay I changed my line object to have float points and that did like 1-2 milliseconds. Still have about 33 milliseconds in onDraw which is just to slow....

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong? Typical screen is from 800x480 to 1920x1080, why do you need to draw 5K lines which will not fit in screen or will look disturbed...

Comment: I'm reading a dxf file of an architectual drawing. I need too zoom and pan like you can do in a CAD programm. These drawings habe alot of lines which i need to display. I noticed that when I zoom in to a scalefactor like 100000, the actual performance gets better although I still draw all 5k lines. The Problem might be the rendering not the actual onDraw. GPU Gers crazy when I Start dragging.

Comment: Pretty wird is that it runs way better on my small Galaxy s2 instead of my nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

35 milliseconds translates to ~ 30 frames per second.

What I always do is paint to a memory bitmap, and then block-transfer it to the window.
First of all, it may be faster during the line-drawing, because it's not clipping for overlapping windows.
Second, the block transfer happens so fast it appears instantaneous.

That way, it appears to paint fast even if it isn't actually.
It's far better than all that flashing you get if you paint directly to the window.

Here's how I do it in C#:

```
    Graphics grToDrawOn = null;
    Bitmap bmToDrawOn = null;
    private void MyWin_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs _e){
        int w = ClientRectangle.Width;
        int h = ClientRectangle.Height;
        Graphics gr = _e.Graphics;
        // if the bitmap needs to be made, do so
        if (bmToDrawOn == null) bmToDrawOn = new Bitmap(w, h, gr);
        // if the bitmap needs to be changed in size, do so
        if (bmToDrawOn.Width != w || bmToDrawOn.Height != h){
            bmToDrawOn = new Bitmap(w, h, gr);
        }
        // hook the bitmap into the graphics object
        grToDrawOn = Graphics.FromImage(bmToDrawOn);
        // clear the graphics object before drawing
        grToDrawOn.Clear(Color.White);
        // paint everything on grToDrawOn
        DoPainting();
        // copy the bitmap onto the real screen
        _e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmToDrawOn, new Point(0,0));
    }
```

Comment: Hey Mike, I'm just starting with this stuff.. could you give a link with examples oder any small example code? I'm currently transforming everything with Matrix object and need to keep track of the translations and scaling to keep original koordinates after translation. would that be a problem with a bitmap?

Comment: @GeoGecco: I'm not a Javista, but I just showed how I do it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Well I added one line of code and now its at least running fine for 5k points.

here is what I added : `this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Thats IT ! =)